# How can I optimize a compute shader that's heavy on imageLoad calls?

Tags: opengl, compute-shader

In my program I have compute shaders that make a lot of imageLoad calls on 3D textures, and they all end in an imageStore to an output texture.

Here's an example that calculates the 3D field's gradient:

```
#version 430 core

layout(local_size_x=4, local_size_y=4, local_size_z=4) in;

layout(rgba16_snorm)
uniform image3D img_in;

layout(rgba16_snorm) 
uniform image3D img_out;

void main()
{
    ivec3 coord = ivec3(gl_GlobalInvocationID);

    float left =    imageLoad(img_in, coord + ivec3(-1,  0,  0)).x;
    float right =   imageLoad(img_in, coord + ivec3( 1,  0,  0)).x;
    float top =     imageLoad(img_in, coord + ivec3( 0,  1,  0)).x;
    float bottom =  imageLoad(img_in, coord + ivec3( 0, -1,  0)).x;
    float front =   imageLoad(img_in, coord + ivec3( 0,  0, -1)).x;
    float back =    imageLoad(img_in, coord + ivec3( 0,  0,  1)).x;
    
    vec3 gradient = vec3(right-left, top-bottom, back-front) / 2;

    imageStore(img_out, coord, vec4(gradient, 0));
}
```

With a 128x128x128 texture, this shader is taking 0.9ms to execute (work group size: 32x32x32). I have a shader to calculate divergence and it takes roughly the same amount of time. Is there anything I can do to speed it up?

Edit: Updated shader code with shared array

```
#version 430 core

layout(local_size_x=4, local_size_y=4, local_size_z=4) in;

layout(rgba16_snorm)
uniform image3D img_in;

layout(rgba16_snorm) 
uniform image3D img_out;

uniform float gs;

shared vec4 cache[4][4][4];

void retire_phase()
{
    memoryBarrierShared();
    barrier();
}

ivec3 clamp_coord(ivec3 coord)
{
    return clamp(coord, ivec3(0, 0, 0), imageSize(img_in));
}

void main()
{
    ivec3 coord = ivec3(gl_GlobalInvocationID);
    vec4 tx = imageLoad(img_in, clamp_coord(coord));

    ivec3 cc = ivec3(mod(coord, ivec3(gl_WorkGroupSize)));
    cache[cc.x][cc.y][cc.z] = tx;

    retire_phase();

    ivec3 size = ivec3(gl_WorkGroupSize);
    
    float left, right, top, bottom, front, back;

    if (coord.x > 0)  { left = cache[cc.x-1][cc.y][cc.z].x; }
    else { left = imageLoad(img_in, coord + ivec3(-1,  0,  0)).x; }

    if (coord.x < (size.x - 1)){ right = cache[cc.x+1][cc.y][cc.z].x; }
    else { right =   imageLoad(img_in, coord + ivec3( 1,  0,  0)).x; }
    
    if (coord.y > 0) { bottom = cache[cc.x][cc.y-1][cc.z].x; }
    else { bottom =  imageLoad(img_in, coord + ivec3( 0, -1,  0)).x; }

    if (coord.y < (size.y - 1)) { top = cache[cc.x][cc.y+1][cc.z].x; }
    else { top = imageLoad(img_in, coord + ivec3( 0,  1,  0)).x; }

    if (coord.z > 0) { front = cache[cc.x][cc.y][cc.z-1].x; }
    else { front =   imageLoad(img_in, coord + ivec3( 0,  0, -1)).x; }

    if (coord.z < (size.z - 1)) { back = cache[cc.x][cc.y][cc.z+1].x; }
    else { back = imageLoad(img_in, coord + ivec3( 0,  0,  1)).x; }

    vec3 gradient = vec3(right-left, top-bottom, back-front) / (2 * gs);

    imageStore(img_out, coord, vec4(gradient, 0));
}
```

Comment: The threads in the group seem to have a lot of overlap. Use every thread in the group to read one texel each, store it to shared memory. Then do the calculation and write to the output. Here's a presentation with a similar approach in 2D: [SIGGRAPH 2012: NVIDIA OpenGL for 2012](https://de.slideshare.net/Mark_Kilgard/siggraph-2012-nvidia-opengl-for-2012)

Comment: Didn't you ask almost the same question like a week ago?

Comment: Is the idea that reading from shared memory is faster than imageLoad? I tried implementing that technique but the shader got a little bit slower. The glsl still has to use imageLoad when the texel it's reading is at the edge of the group's block. And doesnt imageLoad do its own caching?

Comment: Shared memory is by magnitudes faster than image access. If you enlarge the local size by 2 in each dimension, then each thread has to read exactly one texel. then let only the threads [1, n-1] calculate the average and write. If you've done that, I suggest that you update your question with your new shader. Caching: ImageLoad is usually not cached. If you want texture memory caching, you'd have to use texelFetch and a texture.

Comment: I updated my question with the new shader, is that what you are suggesting? I'll see how it responds to doubling the local size from 4 to 8 in each dimension. And look into texelFetch

Edit: nevermind, I guess texelFetch only works on samplers